# Telescopic limit output is different from expected output

Tags: c, floating-point, division

For a school assignment we are supposed to write a short piece of code that calculates the telescopic limit up to 100. The expect answer should be `sum is: 0.99000`
but my output is always `sum is: 0.00000` no matter what I try.

I hope it is a quick fix that I have been overlooking, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out what it is.

here is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float ans=0.0;

    for(int i=1; i<100; i++){
        ans += 1/ (i*(i+1));
    }

    printf("sum is: %.5f",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `1/ (i*(i+1))` is **integer arithmetic** i.e. as it takes integer operands, it will give `int` as output.

Comment: regarding: `float ans=0.0;`   This is assigning a `double` to a `float` value.  Suggest: `float ans=0.0f;`   Notice the trailing `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the expression

```
  1/ (i*(i+1))
```

`i` is of type int, and a `1` (digits) are by default of type `int` (integer constants of type `int`, to be pedantic).

So, all the participating members are of type `int`  and the arithmetic will be integer arithmetic. It is not floating point arithmetic. Thus, for above expression, for any value of `i`, greater than `0`, you'll have a result of `0` as an outcome of integer division.

You need to either

- use a `float` or `double` type operand
- cast one of the operands to `float` or `double`

to *enforce* a floating point arithmetic to get the desired result.